# Popup menu text color is not working, background color working fine

Tags: android

On my main app theme I have:

```
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyApp.PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/MyTextAppearanceLargePopupMenu
    </item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/MyTextAppearanceSmallPopupMenu
    </item>
```

And then I have

```
<style name="MyApp.PopupMenu" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/color_white</item>
    <item name="overlapAnchor">true</item>
    <item name="android:overlapAnchor">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/MyTextAppearanceLargePopupMenu
    </item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/MyTextAppearanceSmallPopupMenu
    </item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextAppearanceLargePopupMenu" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextAppearanceSmallPopupMenu" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

But my popup menu appears with a white background and white letters instead of black. I have tested this by changing the background and that works fine.

So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Edit: Figured it out, my app theme has `<item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>` and that seems to override whatever I do on popup menu styles.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34233329/1512199)

Comment: I can change the background just fine, it is the text color I can't change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I would like to add a point. Need to make sure that the style is applied to  ```android:popupMenuStyle``` instead of ```popupMenuStyle```. I too had the same issue but this helped me...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupStyle</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/PopupTextAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/PopupTextAppearanceSmall</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#ff00ff</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#ff00ff</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupTextAppearanceLarge" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffff00</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupTextAppearanceSmall" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffff00</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Toolbar example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
```

Comment: This example doesn't work for me, it doesn't even change the background color. To get the background color to work I have to put `android:` in front of `popupMenuStyle`.

Comment: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">`

Comment: It must be something with my code though, I created a clean sample and it worked fine.

Comment: Yeah the previous version intended to using for context menus. But i assume you're using toolbar. I updated the answer. This should work

Comment: I'm not using a toolbar for this specific popup menu, I mean the activity has a toolbar but that isn't where the popup menu is. I figured out the issue though. My code has `<item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>` on the main style and that seems to override this.

Answer (score 0):

Its very late but the main reason is that the attribute `android:textColor` is applied to the popup menu which is defined in the main style (parent) and you can't control by defining your style for popup menu. Don't know the reason for this weird functionality but it as it is, its **google** .
So add  `<item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>` in the parent style.